# Phonegap-facebook plug in issue

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I integrated Phonegap-facebook plug in with ionic successfully with parse DB as back end. But when I add android platform, I get this error:

```
Failed to install 'com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect':Error: Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:304:23
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:304:23
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I've added facebook app's id and secret to js files, it gets logged in successfully in localhost hosting, i.e., in web version. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to complete [the install process of the plugin here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md)

First

```
# Remember to replace APP_ID and APP_NAME variables
$ cordova -d plugin add /path/to/cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

After that yuo have to choose the install with or without Eclipse, I recommend without :

```
android update project --subprojects --path "platforms/android" --target android-19 --library "CordovaLib"

android update project --subprojects --path "platforms/android" --target android-19 --library "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib"

cd platforms/android/

ant clean

cd com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookLib

ant clean

open -e AndroidManifest.xml 

// change your minSdkVersion and your targetSdkVersion to your environment settings for me it was:
// <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

ant release

cd ../../..

cordova build android
```